# Slide up hover with JS

Tags: javascript, hover, mouseover

I have a hover effect (with 'div' slide up on a hover), but it works not properly - for some reason it opens on every element in the grid, but I need it to be only on mouseover element

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if($(document).width() > 992) {
    $('.one').hover(function() {
        var color = $(this).css('background-color'),
            hint = $(this).parent().find('.morehover');
        if (($(hint).text()).trim() == "") return 0;
        $(hint).css('border-top-color', color).clearQueue().delay(500).slideDown();
    }, function() {
        var hint = $(this).parent().find('.morehover').first();
        $(hint).clearQueue().delay(500).slideUp();
    });
}});
```

and

```
<div class="one">
  <?= $f_AdminButtons ?>
    <div class="img-logo-cat"> <img src="<?= $f_imagelogocatalogue ?>" alt="">
      <div class="link-not-link">
        <?= $f_linkShow ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image"><img src="<?= $f_phoneImage ?>" alt=""></div>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="more">
      <div class="morehover">
        <?= nc_edit_inline('morehover', $f_RowID, $cc)?>
          <div class="ssilka-podrob"><a class="ssilka-podrob-link" href="<?= $f_linkMore ?>">Подробнее </a><i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></div>
      </div><span><?= nc_edit_inline('Price', $f_RowID, $cc)?></span>
      <a href="<?= $f_buttonLink ?>" class="button" target="_blank">
        <?= $f_buttonText ?>
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: screenshot]

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at this line:

```
hint = $(this).parent().find('.morehover');
```

You are on the element `<div class="one">` and you are selecting the parent element of it than looking for `morehover`. You want the `morehover` inside of the element you are on, so you should NOT be looking at the parent.

```
hint = $(this).find('.morehover');
```

Comment: I'm so dumb! Thank you very very much!